# How can I have a fixed top banner inside a jquery ui dialog?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I currently have a jq ui dialog opening with the size of 875x600. I have a top banner with some info that I would like to keep in that fixed position while the user scrolls the content of the dialog. The dialog is also moveable, so the banner has to obviously stay with it.
Here is the banner code if you need it.  grid_14 is 820px

```
<div class="row" id="PatientHeader">
    <div class="grid_14 patientNameHeader">
        <div class="column grid_14">
            <h2>lastname, firstname</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_14 patientInfoHeader">
        <div class="column grid_6">
            <h2><i>HICN:</i><br></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="column grid_4">
            <h2><i>DOB:</i><br> mm/dd/yyyy</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="column grid_4">
            <h2><i>Sex:</i><br>Female</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I got it staying put with the following code, but if the user moves the dialog or uses the up/down keys, the banner stays in the viewport and not with the dialog.

```
#PatientInfoHeader {
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 #000000;
    color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
    height: 138px;
    padding-top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 95px;
    width: 840px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#ClaimsWrapper{width: 840px; position: absolute;}
#ClaimsContent{position: relative; top: 120px;}
```

Comment: Have you tried absolute positioning on the banner?

Comment: it puts the banner where I need it, but it doesn't stay fixed to the top when the dialog is scrolled.